# error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'

Tags: node.js, npm, pg

Trying to install `pg`. Here's the full log:

```
$ npm install pg --save
npm WARN package.json hs-app@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json hs-app@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json hs-app@0.0.0 No README data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pg
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pg
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/2.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-writer/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/2.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-writer/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cloned/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cloned/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rmdir
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rmdir

> pg@2.3.1 install /Users/David/Developer/hs-app/node_modules/pg
> node-gyp rebuild || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o
../src/binding.cc:49:51: warning: 'New' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    Local<FunctionTemplate> t = FunctionTemplate::New(New);
                                                  ^
../src/binding.cc:54:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    emit_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("emit");
                  ^
../src/binding.cc:55:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    severity_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("severity");
                      ^
../src/binding.cc:56:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    code_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("code");
                  ^
../src/binding.cc:57:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    detail_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("detail");
                    ^
../src/binding.cc:58:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    hint_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("hint");
                  ^
../src/binding.cc:59:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    position_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("position");
                      ^
../src/binding.cc:60:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    internalPosition_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("internalPosition");
                              ^
../src/binding.cc:61:28: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    internalQuery_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("internalQuery");
                           ^
../src/binding.cc:62:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    where_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("where");
                   ^
../src/binding.cc:63:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    file_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("file");
                  ^
../src/binding.cc:64:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    line_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("line");
                  ^
../src/binding.cc:65:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    routine_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("routine");
                     ^
../src/binding.cc:66:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    name_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("name");
                  ^
../src/binding.cc:67:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    value_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("value");
                   ^
../src/binding.cc:68:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    type_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("dataTypeID");
                  ^
../src/binding.cc:69:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    channel_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("channel");
                     ^
../src/binding.cc:70:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    payload_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("payload");
                     ^
../src/binding.cc:71:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NODE_PSYMBOL'
    command_symbol = NODE_PSYMBOL("command");
                     ^
../src/binding.cc:73:45: error: address of overloaded function 'Connect' does not match required type 'void (const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &)'
    NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD(t, "connect", Connect);
                                            ^~~~~~~
../src/binding.cc:447:8: note: candidate function has type mismatch at 1st parameter (expected 'const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &' but has 'const char *')
  bool Connect(const char* conninfo)
       ^
../src/binding.cc:107:3: note: candidate function has type mismatch at 1st parameter (expected 'const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &' but has 'const v8::Arguments &')
  Connect(const Arguments& args)
  ^
/Users/David/.node-gyp/0.11.4/src/node.h:152:60: note: passing argument to parameter 'callback' here
                                      v8::FunctionCallback callback) {
                                                           ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
1 warning and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/David/.nvm/v0.11.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:103:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/Users/David/.nvm/v0.11.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/David/Developer/hs-app/node_modules/pg
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok 
pg@2.3.1 node_modules/pg
├── generic-pool@2.0.3
└── buffer-writer@1.0.0 (async@0.2.9, cloned@0.0.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainer of [`node-postgres`](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), [Brian C](https://github.com/brianc), answered the following in the [issue I had opened](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/422) on github:

The native bindings wont compile on v.0.11.x yet. Every minor version for the past 4 they've substantially changed the C/C++ layer and the native bindings always break. I'm not going to go through the effort of fixing them until closer to the v0.12.0 release because the code is still in flux on node's end and will break again.

Good news, you're not hosed:

1. use the non-native bindings (`require('pg')`) which install even if the compilation fails
2. use node v0.10.x